# How to format HTML table properly in Outlook mailitem

Tags: c#, html, email, outlook

I'm using C# to pragmatically create an outlook mail item that populates an html table. The problem is, when the email is sent it looks like hell on earth in outlook. I understand  everything formats differently in outlook versus chrome. I understand that html elements need to contain inline styles, and that i cannot use CSS. Knowing all of this and creating a nice inline table in Brackets IDE and then using the same code in C# and sending an email to outlook, it still looks terrible.

How can I accomplish a decent formatted table using HTML/outlook??

Here is some of my C# code.

```
 sb.Append("<table border=\"1px solid black\";>");
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<th style=\"1px solid black\";>{0}</th>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<th style=\"1px solid black\";>{0}</th>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<th style=\"1px solid black\";>{0}</th>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<th style=\"1px solid black\";>{0}</th>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<th style=\"1px solid black\";>{0}</th>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<th style=\"1px solid black\";>{0}</th>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<th style=\"1px solid black\";>{0}</th>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<th style=\"1px solid black\";>{0}</th>");
        sb.Append("</tr>");
        sb.Append("</table>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you target Outlook mail client only,  I would suggest to create table in one of the Microsoft tools - either in Outlook itself or Word. In Outlook you have to view raw email to get email markup, for Word you can save document as HTML.

2) In your example code it seems that 'border' part is missing in your style attributes.

```
sb.AppendFormat("<th style=\"border: 1px solid black\";>{0}</th>");
```

I guess it works in browser because browsers tolerate badly formatted markup pretty good, while Outlook not so much.

Comment: So when my code runs and returns data, it is possible at runtime to create a word table and populate that table, and then add that table to outlook and send the e-mail? This is going to be an automated service.

Comment: @Mattaceten If you want to generate HTML, I would recommend to use some templating engine. One of the best ways would be to use Razor engine that is part of ASP.NET. Take a look at this NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine/. You will still need to write Outlook specific markup, but you will be able to populate elements with data more easily.